# combinatorics Question: How to create a schedule for 6 teams playing x number of games

Tags: combinatorics

How to create a schedule for 6 teams playing x number of games no team can play same team twice no team can play same game twice

Comment: There are total  $\binom{6}{2}x=15x$ matches.

Comment: Thank you, we have one problem We would like to play 6 games, but we keep over lapping teams play each other or not play all the games?

Comment: If you play 6 games total, and each game involves 2 teams, then on average each team only has 2 games.  Is that what you want?  Or perhaps each game involves 3 or more teams?  Or perhaps you really mean there are 6 rounds, or, each team plays 6 games?

Comment: Let $x=1$ then this is a common problem faced by e.g. any sportsleague. The problem can be reduced to finding an edge coloring in a complete graph. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm, or http://tournamentscheduler.net/